# Error occurred ... no database selected

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to connect to a database, check a column for whether a value exists or not, then execute a function based on whether or not that value exists.

Here's my code.

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','','users');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM allUsers WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]) . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die("Error occurred in [$sql]: " . mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count != 0){
    echo "Username is already taken";
    echo "$count";
    mysql_close($con);
}

else{
    createUser($_POST["name"],$_POST["username"],$_POST["password"],$_POST["email"]);
    }
```

The thrown error is:

> Error occurred in [SELECT * FROM allUsers WHERE username = 'Admin']: No database selected.

I'm almost entirely sure that it comes from the `$result` line, but haven't a clue as to why.

I feel like this is a simple solution, and I'm just missing something minor.

I'm very new to MySQL (today is my first day, actually), so please keep solutions as simple as possible.

Comment: If you're new to PHP, then stop learning using the MySQL library, and start learning using MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements

Comment: The system says: "No database selected". Hm, maybe you should select one. Google for "php select database" to get hints of how that can be done. And PLEASE remember that the `mysql` extension is deprecated and gets removed from PHP. Use `mysqli` for new code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about googling the error message and fix the error.

Comment: @Sven, thanks for the help.  For some reason, googling the error message didn't yield any results for me, or the explanations of a possible solution were over my head.  Also, I'll use mysqli in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to call [**`mysql_select_db`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) after connecting:

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('users', $con);
```

Unlike MySQLi or PDO, mysql_* libraries does not take database as argument on the connection string, however if you were to migrate to either MySQLi or PDO.

MySQLi:

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'users');
```

PDO:

```
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users', 'root', '');
```

In MySQLi your code would look like this:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$database = "users";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$database);
if($con->connect_error)
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM allUsers WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST["username"]);

if (!$stmt->execute())
    die('Failed to excute with error ' . $con->error);

$stmt->store_result();
$count = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->close();
if ($count > 0)
{
    echo "Username is already taken.";
}
else
{
    createUser($_POST["name"],$_POST["username"],$_POST["password"],$_POST["email"]);
}
```

Comment: This makes a ton of sense, but when I do it, it starts throwing errors all over the place.

For example: `Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given`

Comment: @IanZane you're trying to use `mysqli_select_db()` on a mysql_* library it won't work, you should use `mysql_select_db()` for mysql_* and `mysqli_select_db` for MySQLi library. Also it should not be `mysql_select_db()` you must provide the database name `mysql_select_db('users')`

Comment: Wait, I got it, the problem was giving $con as the second parameter.  It works fine when $con comes first.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is quite obvious, you need to specify the database you want.

`mysql_select_db("databaseName", $con);`

With that taken care of, please, please don't use `mysql_` libraries the are vulnerable to SQL injection and will soon be removed.